# extJS 3.2.1 AJAX request while refreshing other lists

Tags: extjs

I have a grid control which I reload via a timer every second or so. I initiate this timer immediately before calling a AJAX request which is long processing at times.

The grid I am refreshing is actually a list of tasks to be carried out on the server.

I am trying to give the user some ideas as to how much longer they have to wait.

this code:

```
  var task = {
    run: function(){
      Ext.getCmp("id_task_approval_progress").store.reload();
    },
    interval: 1000
  }

  var runner = new Ext.util.TaskRunner();
  runner.start(task); 

  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: 'services/index.php/application/task/approve',
    params: { id_primary: id_task, id_status: status },
    success: function(response, action){
      if(!ajax_error_handler(response, action)){
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    }
  });
```

Does not work...it prevents the grid from refreshing until the AJAX request is complete???

Using ExtJS 3.2.1 - what am I doing wrong? Is there a work around or setting?

Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think that several requests were sent to server and the issue isn't related to the client side (apache config or how php works with sessions). If yes - please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739709/how-to-configure-php-or-apache-for-non-blocking-http-requests).